# How do I ensure SerializeJSON keeps trailing/leading zeroes?

Tags: json, serialization, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

**EDIT 3** Problem below exists for Coldfusion 9.0, updating to 9.0.1 does indeed fix this

I have an application that is using SerializeJSON to encode  query results:

```
#SerializeJSON('Ok works fine')#
```

Unfortunately it trims the trailing zeroes from numbers:

```
#SerializeJSON(12345.50)#
```

manually if i was to make the same value a string, same thing occurs

```
#SerializeJSON('12345.50')#
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT** - my scenario specifics

Database (Oracle) has these example values stored on a row

- benefactor_id : 0000729789 varchar2(10)
- life_gift_credit_amt : 12345.50 number(14,2)

When I query using Coldfusion 9.0.1 (cfscript if it matters) , here is an RC dump, notice the id string retains leading zeroes, but the number column has removed trailing zero. 
[image]
While that is interesting, it doesnt matter to the Original issue as i can create a query manually to retain that trailing zero like below, it still gets lost in the serializeJSON
[image]

I take the query results, and encode the values using serializeJSON. The JSON is consumed by jquery Datatables ajax. Notice the id string has become a number, and has added the '.0' as Miguel-F mentioned

```
<cfscript>
...
  rc.sql = q.setsql;
  rc.qResult = q.execute().getresult();

  savecontent variable="rc.aaData" {
    for (i=1; i <= rc.qResult.RecordCount; i++) {
      writeOutput('{');
      for (col=1; col <= iColumnsLen; col++) {
        // the following line contains a conditional specific to this example
        writeOutput('"#aColumns[col]#":#SerializeJSON(rc.qResult[aColumns[col]][i])#'); 
        //former statement, discarded due to not being able to handle apostrophe's ... writeOutput('"#jsStringFormat(rc.qResult[aColumns[col]][i])#"');
        writeOutput((col NEQ iColumnsLen) ? ',' : '');
      }
      writeOutput('}');
      writeOutput((i NEQ rc.qResult.RecordCount) ? ',' : '');
    }
  };
</cfscript>
```

I was oringially using jsStringFormat instead of serializeJSON, but this would return invalid JSON due to the comments text area containing apostrophe's ect

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 65970,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 7657,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "nd_event_id": 525,
            "benefactor_id": 729789.0,
            "seq_number": 182163,
            "life_gift_credit_amt": 12345.5,
            "qty_requested": 2,
            "b_a_comment": "#swap",
            "pref_mail_name": "Jay P. Rizzi"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 2**

a quick sidenote, if i change my serialization line to

```
writeOutput('"#aColumns[col]#": "#SerializeJSON(rc.qResult[aColumns[col]][i])#"');
```

then my result set changes to placing records in double quoting , but also double double quotes strings, while still removing the trailing zero; It leads me to believe serializeJSON is casting the value as a type?

```
"aaData": [
    {
        "nd_event_id": "525",
        "benefactor_id": "729789.0",
        "seq_number": "182163",
        "life_gift_credit_amt": "12345.5",
        "qty_requested": "2",
        "b_a_comment": ""#swap"",
        "pref_mail_name": ""JayP.Rizzi""
    },
```

Comment: Why do you want them?  They are insignificant on the right side of the decimal. You could add them back using a mask for display if needed.

Comment: _"Why do you want them?"_ - because it's a string and they may have significance. (If it's user provided text, there's no way to know in advance what is in the field and whether it can/should be reformatted.)

Comment: Jay, what version of CF? Just tried with both 9 and 10 and it doesn't remove the zero. Oh... CF10 doesn't quote the value (so it's considered a number in the JSON) - adding a space to the start of the value gets it output as string (doesn't work adding space to end of value) - not a great solution though. :/

Comment: Im using 9.0.1, it doesnt quote the value for a number in that version as well, i shouldve reflected that in original q

Comment: Well you can [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16679118/edit) to add that info. :) (It's more visible than comments that way.) Can't remember what I tried - thought it was 9.0.2 but perhaps it was only 9.0.0

Comment: @PeterBoughton I believe the `SerializeJSON()` function is treating it as a number and that is why it drops the trailing zero, hence my comment. If it were treated as a string no characters would be truncated.

Comment: SerializeJSON doesn't drop the zero - it just doesn't add quotes, causing _whatever is consuming the JSON_ to treat is as a number. Since CF internally stores all simple values as strings, you can actually do `#SerializeJSON(12345.50)#` and it still retains the zero. Also interesting is that whilst you get no quotes with `#SerializeJSON('12345.50 ')#` you do get the trailing space. \*shrug\*

Comment: I am finding all kinds of discussion about this on the web and apparently changes were made in 9.0.1 (bug 83638) - [Reference 1](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/7/21/Not-happy-with-the-CF901-JSON-Changes), [Reference 2](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-1-chf1-coldfusion.html). And if you search the [BugBase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=search) for JSON under version 9.0.1 there are several. Apparently ColdFusion 8 used to append a '.0' to all integers. What you are seeing now was the "fix".

Comment: @PeterBoughton makes a good point (as usual), _SerializeJSON doesn't drop the zero - it just doesn't add quotes_. Can you tell us what you are using to consume the JSON? Then we may be able to provide an answer as to how to keep the zero.

Comment: @Miguel-F updated/edited my original question with the specific use instance of how I encountered this

Comment: From my testing (on 9.0.1) the SerializeJSON function does NOT drop the trailing zero, but the DeSerializeJSON function does (unless the number is enclosed in quotes) just as @bphillips mentioned in his answer. It looks like you are seeing different behavior? It also seems odd that you are seeing the ".0" being appended to the id. That was a "feature" of ColdFusion 8 and was fixed in ColdFusion 9.0.1.

Comment: I want to apologize, I had installed 9.0.1 months ago, but due to an ANT non-fatal error on install, 9.0.1 was never applied, was still on 9.0.0.25 :/  in any case, once update was applied correctly , serializeJSON does not add .0's or remove trailing zeroes

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting that. It helps explain all of the confusion. Please post it as an answer to your own question and accept it so that others will find it more easily.

Comment: Miguel if you want to post this i'll gladly accept it as the answer, your comments is what drove me to investigation

Comment: Ok, I can do that but I need to leave for a while. I will post back if you have not already answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taken from the comments*

The original poster (OP) of this question initially reported that they were having this issue with ColdFusion 9.0.1. As it turned out they were actually running ColdFusion 9.0.0. This is significant because Adobe had made changes to how the `SerializeJSON()` function treats numbers in version 9.0.1. When the server was upgraded to version 9.0.1 these issues were resolved.

This blog post by Raymond Camden discusses the changes made in 9.0.1 - [Not happy with the CF901 JSON Changes?](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/7/21/Not-happy-with-the-CF901-JSON-Changes)

In that blog post he references bug 83638 that had been entered and then fixed in HotFix 1 for version 9.0.1 - [Cumulative Hotfix 1 (CHF1) for ColdFusion 9.0.1](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/cumulative-hotfix-1-chf1-coldfusion.html)

If you search the [BugBase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=search) for JSON under version 9.0.1 there are several reporting the same issue as the OP.

Those reported bugs also mentioned another issue that the OP had not initially reported, that a `.0` was being appended to integers as well. Later in the discussion the OP confirmed that they too were seeing this behavior. This lead them to verify the ColdFusion version being utilized and found that it was not 9.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit baffling... I tested in CF 9 as well. Not really knowing what you are doing with the serialized data (passing as a service, outputting on a page, etc.), I put together some test patterns. One possible solution is if only trying to serialize a sing value - don't. You can actually run deserialize against your numeric value without serializing, and all it does is strip the trailing 0. Otherwise, if you must serialize a single value and don't want the trailing 0 stripped, set the variable to contain the quotation marks

```
<cfset manualserial = '"111.10"'>
<cfdump var="#DeSerializeJson(manualserial)#">
```

At this point you can us Deserialize and see that it maintains the 0, with output of 111.10
Below is some additional testing, so you can see what happens when serializing an array while trying to keep the trailing 0... no luck. However when I forwent the built in CF serialize and just created a serialized string, the trailing 0 is maintained (refer to var customarr and d_customarr in WriteDump example below).

Hope that helps a little.

```
<cfscript>
/*initial testing*/
string = SerializeJSON('Ok works fine');
numericstring = SerializeJSON('12345.50');
numeric = SerializeJSON(12345.50);
arr =  SerializeJSON([12345.50,12345.10,'12345.20']);
arrFormat = SerializeJSON([NumberFormat(12345.50,'.00') & ' ',12345.10,'12345.20']);

d_string = DeSerializeJSON(string);
d_numericstring = DeSerializeJSON(numericstring);
d_numeric = DeSerializeJSON(numeric);
d_arr = DeSerializeJSON(arr);
d_arrFormat = DeSerializeJSON(arrFormat);


/*technically, there is no need to serialize a single string value, as running through DeSerialize just trims the trailing 0
if you need to do so, you would want to pass in as a string with quotation marks*/
customstring = '"12345.50"';
d_customstring  = DeSerializeJSON(customstring);
customarr = '["12345.50","12345.10","12345.20"]';   //--you can format your own array instead of using CF to serialize 
d_customarr  = DeSerializeJSON(customarr);

WriteDump(variables);
</cfscript>
```

**=======appended possible solution b========**

I think that manually serializing your records may be the most stable option, try this example, and if it works you should be able to add the function to a cfc or create a udf for re-use. Hope it helps.

```
<cfscript>
q = QueryNew('nd_event_id,benefactor_id,seq_number,life_gift_credit_amt,qty_requested,b_a_comment,pref_mail_name',
            'Integer,VarChar,Integer,Decimal,Integer,VarChar,VarChar');
r = queryaddrow(q,2);   
querysetcell(q, 'nd_event_id', 525, 1);
querysetcell(q, 'benefactor_id', 0000729789, 1);    
querysetcell(q, 'seq_number', 182163, 1);
querysetcell(q, 'life_gift_credit_amt', 12345.50, 1);   
querysetcell(q, 'qty_requested', 2, 1); 
querysetcell(q, 'b_a_comment', '##swap', 1);    
querysetcell(q, 'pref_mail_name', 'Jay P. Rizzi', 1);       
querysetcell(q, 'nd_event_id', 525, 2);
querysetcell(q, 'benefactor_id', 0000729790, 2);
querysetcell(q, 'seq_number', 182164, 2);   
querysetcell(q, 'life_gift_credit_amt', 12345.90, 2);   
querysetcell(q, 'qty_requested', 10, 2);    
querysetcell(q, 'b_a_comment', '##swap', 2);    
querysetcell(q, 'pref_mail_name', 'Jay P. Rizzi', 2);   
WriteDump(q);

s = membershipManualSerializer(q);

public string function membershipManualSerializer(required query q){
    var jsonString = '{"aaData":[';
    var cols = listtoarray(q.columnList,',');

    for(var i=1; i lte q.recordcount; i++){

        jsonString &= "{";

        for(var c=1;c lte arraylen(cols);c++){
            jsonString &= '"' & cols[c] & '":"' & q[cols[c]][i] & '"';
            jsonString &= (c lt arraylen(cols))? ",":"";
        }

        jsonString &= (i lt q.recordcount)? "},":"}]";
    }

    jsonString &="}";

    return jsonString;
}


WriteOutput(s);
WriteDump(DeserializeJson(s));      
</cfscript>
```